# Set nodejs project directory based on the URL

Tags: node.js, express, router

I am currently serving angular1 application over node js app. 
I want to serve my angular1 app as well as angular2 app from same domain with this node server. 
I have following setting in my app.js of node js file:

```
var staticDir = nodeEnv == 'development' ? path.join(__dirname, '/home/sovf/ang1/') : '/data/project/angular/app';
```

My angular1 project directory is here: /home/sovf/ang1/
My angular2 project directory is here: /home/svof/ang2/

How can I configure the staticDir to use '/home/svof/ang2/' , when the url matches /ang2/*

I have tried enogh to look for resources and node configuration for this but could not find anything. Can any one please help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new instance of `express.static` that uses `/home/svof/ang2` as root directory (where it should look for the static resources), and "mount" that instance on `/ang2`, so it will only match requests that start with that prefix:

```
app.use('/ang2', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/home/svof/ang2')));
```

Comment: I tried adding this:
app.use('/new/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/home/svof/ang2')));

But this time stattic resources are not loading, I am getting this error in console:
Can not get GET https://hostname/inline.bundle.js 
Not sure where I am missing

Comment: it seems to have picked index.html correctly but not the JS files.

Comment: What's the directory structure and how are you requesting the JS files from the HTML? Ideally, you need to use absolute paths (`/ang2/js/somefile.js`)

Comment: I am refrencing like this:

<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script>

Comment: My bad.. was doing silly mistake.. thanks a lot @robertklep